# How to Hide/Show of UI component in oracle adf

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I am new to oracle adf in my application one of the field is id and it is sequence generated value Whenever I entered remaining values and click on save then only it has to display with sequence generated value before saving it has to be in hide mode. Can any one help me how the approach is.

Comment: if you could maybe take a bit more time to describe what you want to do. It is very hard to make out exactly what you want the screen to do. Maybe ask someone with better English skills to help you write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set visible property for seq field. like below

```
visible="#{binding.filedName.inputValue != null}"
```

by default seq field value is null so it will not display. once u click save button, this field value to be set to next seq value so it will display

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this value from UI and do your number generation for this field in model.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visible attribute of the field in your page to be based on an expression language such as #{viewScope.showfield}, then add a setPropertyListener to your save button that sets the #{viewScope.showfield} to true.